# setRecreateMountedPagesAfterExpiry changes URL to servlet

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

We recently upgraded the application from Wicket 1.5.8 to 6.22.0. I am trying to set all pages to redirect to a specific page (SessionExpiredPage) when an action occurs after the session has expired.

```
public class WicketApplication<HttpsRequestCycleProcessor> extends WebApplication
{
    // other methods omitted

    public void init()
    {
        super.init();

        getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);
        getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);
        getPageSettings().setRecreateMountedPagesAfterExpiry(false);

        // several other mounted links omitted      
        mount(new MountedMapper("landingpage", LandingPage.class, new UrlPathPageParametersEncoder()));

        // add your configuration here
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
    }
}
```

Setting setRecreateMountedPagesAfterExpiry to false helps redirect several pages upon session expiry, however there is an unintended consequence. The application contains several servlet pages. One of them is accessed from a wicket page like this:

```
@RequireHttps
public class SubscriptionPage extends WebPage
{
    @Override
    public void onSubmit()
    {
        String redirectUrl = null;

        // condition checking code omitted
        redirectUrl= "SubsCartTempServlet?subsunit=6";

        // more code omitted
        getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RedirectRequestHandler(redirectUrl));
    }
}
```

The url is changed from http://localhost:8080/LatinParserK/SubsCartTempServlet?subsunit=6, which worked, to
http://localhost:8080/LatinParserK/wicket/SubsCartTempServlet?subsunit=6, which fails.

Can anyone explain how to work around this problem?

Comment: What is the mount path for SubscriptionPage? And what is the servlet mapping for SubsCartTempServlet?

Comment: `mount(new MountedMapper("subscriptionpage", SubscriptionPage.class, new UrlPathPageParametersEncoder()));`

Comment: `  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SubsCartTempServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.linguaclassica.parser.SubsCartTempServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SubsCartTempServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SubsCartTempServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the path to the Wicket page and to the Servlet have different depth.

Use `org.apache.wicket.request.UrlUtils#rewriteToContextRelative(relativeUrl, cycle)` to make the url to the Servlet relative to the context root.

Answer (score 0):

The last line under onSubmit() was replaced with:

```
String relativeUrl = UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative(redirectUrl, getRequestCycle());
getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RedirectRequestHandler(relativeUrl));
```

That corrected the URL to the servlet.